# javascript, array of string as JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, post

I'm having problems with passing two arrays of strings as arguments in JSON format to invoke ASMX Web Service method via jQuery's "POST".

My Web Method is:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public List<string> CreateCollection(string[] names, string[] lastnames)
        {
            this.collection = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                this.collection.Add(names[i] + " " + lastnames[i]);
            }
            return this.collection;
        }
```

Now, the js:

```
function CreateArray() {
            var dataS = GetJSONData(); //data in JSON format (I believe)
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:45250/ServiceJava.asmx/CreateCollection",
                data: dataS,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //something
                }
            })
        }
```

`GetJSONData()` is my helper method creating two arrays from column in a table. Here's the code:

```
function GetJSONData() {
            //take names
            var firstnames = $('#data_table td:nth-child(1)').map(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get(); //["One","Two","Three"]

            //take surnames
            var surnames = $('#data_table td:nth-child(2)').map(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get(); //["Surname1","Surname2","Surname3"]

            //create JSON data
            var dataToSend = {
                names: JSON.stringify(firstnames),
                lastnames: JSON.stringify(surnames)
            };
            return dataToSend;
        }
```

Now, when I try to execude the code by clicking button that invokes `CreateArray()` I get the error:

> ExceptionType: "System.ArgumentException" Message: "Incorrect first
>   JSON element: names."

I don't know, why is it incorrect? I've ready many posts about it and I don't know why it doesn't work, what's wrong with that `dataS`?

**EDIT:** 
Here's `dataToSend` from debugger for

```
var dataToSend = {
                    names: firstnames,
                    lastnames: surnames,
                };
```

as it's been suggested for me to do.

[image]

**EDIT2:**
There's something with those `""` and `''` as @Vijay Dev mentioned, because when I've tried to pass  `data` as `data: "{names:['Jan','Arek'],lastnames:['Karol','Basia']}",` it worked.

So, `stringify()` is not the best choice here, is there any other method that could help me to do it fast?

Comment: Can you share your Json object to see what structure of Json you are trying to posting?

Comment: What exactly should I share? I've written, it's `dataToSend'. How can I get details about it?

Comment: Am referring to `dataS` values.

Comment: @Oluwafemi I've just updated the post, please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think since you are already `JSON.stringifying` values for `dataToSend` property, jQuery might be trying to sending it as serialize data. Trying removing `JSON.stringify` from here:

```
//create JSON data
var dataToSend = {
    names    : firstnames,
    lastnames : surnames
};
```

jQuery will stringify the data when this is set `dataType: "json"`.

Good luck, have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I get the exact error after that change.

Comment: Can you `console.log( dataToSend )` and make sure that the `names` property is getting a valid Array. Also that `.text()` can also return values with `"`  and `'`, which can mess up JSON structure.

Comment: I've edited my post, see the result from `console.log(dataToSend)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending like this:

```
function CreateArray() {
        var dataS = GetJSONData(); //data in JSON format (I believe)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:45250/ServiceJava.asmx/CreateCollection",
            data: {names: dataS.firstnames,lastnames: dataS.surnames} ,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //something
            }
        })
    }
```

This should work..

Comment: I've tried that too, but still the same result, I mean the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Altough, none of the answer was correct, it led me to find the correct way to do this. To make it work, I've made the following change:

```
//create JSON data
    var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ "names": firstnames, "lastnames": surnames });
```

So this is the idea proposed by @Oluwafemi, yet he suggested making `Users` class. Unfortunately, after that, the app wouldn't work in a way it was presented. So I guess if I wanted to pass a custom object I would need to pass it in a different way.

**EDIT:**
I haven't tried it yet, but I think that if I wanted to pass a custom object like this suggested by @Oluwafemi, I would need to write in a script:

```
var user1 = {
            name: "One",
            lastname:"OneOne"
        }
```

and later pass the data as:

```
data = JSON.stringify({ user: user1 });
```

and for an array of custom object, by analogy:

```
data = JSON.stringify({ user: [user1, user2] });
```

I'll check that one later when I will have an opportunity to.